# При запуске телегерамм на kubuntu 22.10 процессор загружается на 90%+. На windows 10 такой проблемы нету

Tags: telegram, загрузка

[image: Высокая нагрузка на CPU telegram]

При запуске телегерамм на kubuntu 22.10 процессор загружается на 90%+. На windows 10 такой проблемы нету

Comment: ну не запускай на убунте